# Animated World background color doesn't show in the viewport

Tags: rendering

I wanted to change the background color over time, according to a sine wave, fed in a mix shader. The problem is, even if i added keyframes to value to change over time, the animation is doing well, but in the render tab, background color stays the same. Does somebody know where's the problem ?[image: Render does not act like it's supposed to]

Comment: In the viewport shading enable "Scene World"  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkwqA.gif